# gcloud snapshot all disks attached to an instance

Tags: instance, gcloud, snapshot, disk

I'm using the gcloud cli api and I'm trying to write a script that creates a snapshot of all disks attached to an instance.

My problem is that the snapshot cli command requires the name of the disk however when I ask gcloud for a list of disks attached to an instance it doesn't (directly) give me the disk name.

If I run:
gcloud compute instances list  --format=json

I get a json array of disks which includes the deviceName but not the name.
I do note that the array includes a 'source' attribute which contains a url which does end with the diskname.
However I'm concerned that parsing the diskname from the url won't provide a stable solution.

So what is the correct way to obtain the disk names?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tired:

```
gcloud compute disks list --format=json ?
```

I don't know if it can be listed by instance, but it contains information by which instance particular disc is used ([reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/list))

I hope it will help!